# How to tile a "wet room" style bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, tile, ceramic-tile

I have 2 rectangular bathroom that are buing built in a wet room style (curbless open shower, drain in blue with all edges sloping towards it, see below). It was already properly sloped and now we were trying to find some small tiles (like 15x15cm or 20x20cm) so that the slope is properly mantained.

So far no luck, I could only find solid color 'pool tiles' in this size, anything "pretty" is in a large format (50x50cm upwards) which would have lots of cuts to follow the slope. Even 30x30cm with minimum cuts would look strange (see below simulation).

Is it ok to use the 'pool tiles'? I don't know if they are ok for bathroom floors and how much slippery they will be.

Simulation 30x30cm tiles on my bathroom:
[image]

What I'm trying to avoid at all costs.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific tile in mind, and you have seen this in a store, simply try the slipperyness out by making it wet and rubbing on it.

There should be nothing wrong with using a pool tile for a bathroom (except maybe slipperyness), since a bathroom is made waterproof underneath the tiles. If the membrane is intact, you can use any tile meant for wet conditions. If the membrane isn't intact, you need to do the whole thing over and redo it anyway, regardless of your tile choice.

Now, I don't know what tiles you like and find pretty, but at least where I live (Denmark), you can get most tiles in sizes from 5x5 cm and up to 31,5x31,5 cm (and some up to 60x60 cm). Some smaller tiles come in sheets of mosaic tiles on a plastic net.

A qick search on my local stores yielded several mosaic tiles (30x30 cm sheets of 5x5 cm tiles) that were labelled as "not slippery" and generally tiles in all sizes and colours.

Comment: We do have the 30x30 sheets of 2.5 and 5 cm tiles here too, but they are usually used just for accent or some details, as they are VERY expensive. They START costing around 9 time as much as regular tiles (as they are sold per sheet instead of square meter, and each sheet is usually more expensive than a single square meter of "regular tile").

Comment: Ah, here they come in prices ranging from the prices of the midrange tiles pr square meter and up (sure, some go very high in prices).